# socket inputstream trouble. appears as null

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, inputstream, soa

i can't seem to figure out what is going on with this code (i didn't write it). it looks like 
`str3 = localBufferedReader1.readLine()` is null and hence an exception is thrown. The output i see after running the application is as follows:

```
  >> Transmitting File : C:/some_folder/another_folder/folder/bin/msg/somefile.soa (32 bytes)
     >> Segment read from file (segLength=15 bytes, 16 bytes remaining to send)
     >> Segment read from file (segLength=13 bytes, 2 bytes remaining to send)
  >> Message sent ...
Exception in Transmitting Data : null
```

I can't seem to understand why there is nothing to read when the connection did not fail and the file was found..? what other reasons could this fail for? i've ensured that the server is really listening on the port number i enter. i'm also running on localhost - so this should work :S i believe that i should be getting a message back (looking at the code) from the socket letting me know if everything is OK or NOT-OK ... any ideas? any help would be appreciated!

```
public class Client
{

  public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString)
    throws IOException
  {
    Socket localSocket = null;
    PrintWriter localPrintWriter = null;
    BufferedReader localBufferedReader1 = null;




    String str1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Host to Talk to ?", "Specify the HOST", 1);



    String str2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What Port is it Listening on ?", "Specify the PORT", 1);
    int i;
    try
    {
      i = Integer.parseInt(str2);
    }
    catch (Exception localException1)
    {
      i = 3128;
    }
    char[] arrayOfChar1 = { '\013' };
    char[] arrayOfChar2 = { '\034' };
    char[] arrayOfChar3 = { '\r' };

    int k = 1;
    int m = 0;
    int n = 0;


    String str3 = "";
    String str5 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Filename Containing HL7 Message", "Test Filename", 1);
    while (str5.length() > 0)
    {
      try
      {
        localSocket = new Socket(str1, i);
        localPrintWriter = new PrintWriter(localSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        System.out.println(localSocket.getInputStream().available()); 

        localBufferedReader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(localSocket.getInputStream()));
      }
      catch (UnknownHostException localUnknownHostException)
      {
        System.out.println("Don't know about host: " + str1);
        System.exit(1);
      }
      catch (IOException localIOException)
      {
        System.out.println("Couldn't get I/O for the Connection to " + str1 + " on Port (" + str2 + ")");
        System.exit(1);
      }
      try
      {
        File localFile = new File(str5);
        BufferedReader localBufferedReader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(localFile));

        long l = localFile.length();
        System.out.println("  >> Transmitting File : " + str5 + " (" + l + " bytes)");

        String str7 = new String(arrayOfChar1);
        String str6;
        while ((str6 = localBufferedReader2.readLine()) != null)
        {
          l = l - str6.length() - 1L;
          System.out.println("     >> Segment read from file (segLength=" + str6.length() + " bytes, " + l + " bytes remaining to send)");
          if (k != 0) {
            k = 0;
          }
          str7 = str7 + str6 + new String(arrayOfChar3);
          if (l < 6L)
          {
            if ((str7.indexOf("READY") >= 0) || (str7.indexOf("BYE") >= 0)) {
              str7 = str7.substring(0, str7.length() - 1);
            } else {
              str7 = str7 + new String(arrayOfChar2);
            }
            m = 1;
          }
          if (m != 0) {
            break;
          }
        }
        if (m == 0)
        {
          str7 = str7 + new String(arrayOfChar2);
          m = 1;
        }
        localPrintWriter.println(str7);
        localPrintWriter.flush();
        localBufferedReader2.close();
        System.out.println("  >> Message sent ...");


        str3 = localBufferedReader1.readLine();
        if (arrayOfChar3[0] == '\r')
        {
          n = 1;
          if (str3.indexOf("SOA|OK|") >= 0) {
            if (str3.indexOf("SOA|OK|||") >= 0)
            {
              if (str3.indexOf("SOA|OK||||") >= 0) {
                n = 0;
              }
            }
            else {
              n = 0;
            }
          }
          if (str3.indexOf("SOA|NOT-OK|") >= 0) {
            n = 0;
          }
          str3 = str3.substring(1) + "\n";
          while (n != 0)
          {
            String str4 = localBufferedReader1.readLine();
            int j = str4.length() - 1;
            if (str4.charAt(j) == arrayOfChar2[0]) {
              n = 0;
            } else {
              str3 = str3 + str4 + "\n";
            }
          }
        }
        System.out.println("  >> Server Responds : " + str3);
      }
      catch (Exception localException2)
      {
        System.out.println("Exception in Transmitting Data : " + localException2.getMessage());
        localPrintWriter.close();
        localBufferedReader1.close();
        localSocket.close();
        System.exit(1);
      }
      localPrintWriter.close();
      localBufferedReader1.close();
      localSocket.close();
      if (str3.indexOf("AE") >= 0) {
        break;
      }
      str5 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Filename Containing HL7 Message", "Test Filename", 1);
      if (str5 == null) {
        System.exit(0);
      }
      k = 1;
      m = 0;
    }
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Print and post the stack trace.

Comment: @EJP java.lang.NullPointerExceptionException in Transmitting Data : null

 at clientPackage.Client.main(Client.java:119)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [javadoc of BufferedReader.readLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29):

**Returns:**
    A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

The code where str3 is used:

```
str3 = localBufferedReader1.readLine();
if (arrayOfChar3[0] == '\r')
{
  n = 1;
  if (str3.indexOf("SOA|OK|") >= 0) {
```

So your code reaches end of stream, and `null` is assigned to str3. However the code doesn't seem to check it and tries to invoke `indexOf` on it.

Comment: yes but there is nothing in the stream to begin with.... it's just null immediately. however, this really shouldn't be the case if everything else was fine, correct?

Comment: If there is nothing in the stream to begin with it will return `null`, but that doesn't stop the code, as far as I can tell. The check of `arrayOfChar3[0] == '\r'` seems to be a tautology by the way.

Comment: well so from what i can tell, the first time it hits str3 = localBufferedReader1.readLine(); str3 is null and it fails at if (str3.indexOf("SOA|OK|") >= 0) since str3 is null and hence the exception is thrown. at least after stepping through, this is what appears to be happening :S

Comment: Exactly, this is what a static code analysis shows. The code ought to check whether str3 is not null.